# Kohana 2.3.4 + LINUX - ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class not found

Tags: php, linux, kohana, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting a Class not found error in Kohana 2.3.4 on my Linux machine but everything runs fine on Windows.

My Windows Machine:

- PHP Version 5.2.9
- Windows 7 Ultimate Edition

My Linux Machine:

- PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15
- Ubuntu 10.04

Im getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'calafate_orm' not found in /home/jay/workspace/Facebook_App/application/helpers/user.php on line 514
```

This is how I call the model:

```
   //controllers/user.php
   class User_Core{

        ...

       $fbuser = calafate_orm::factory('fbuser')->where('fbid', $user['id'])->find();

        ...
    }
```

The same code runs fine on Windows.

The calafate_orm is like this:

```
//libraries/calafate_orm.php 
    <?php
abstract class calafate_orm_core extends ORM{
    protected $db = 'calafate';
    protected $table_names_plural = false;

    public function save(){
        $field          = ($this->id)?'modification_date':'creation_date';
        $this->$field   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        parent::save();
    }

}
?>
```

All of my filenames are on lower case.

What could be happening?

Thanks in advance

FIXED

Library class names and file names begin with a capitalized letter.

Renamed the library to Calafate_orm and edited the class declaration like this:

```
<?php
abstract class Calafate_orm_core extends ORM{
...
}?>
```

And that's it.

Thanks to hakre for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: check with the specification of the kohana auto-loader how the filenames must be written properly (the case!). Windows will eat everything, Linux is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I've reinstalled php 5.3.10 with some extensions and this is not happening anymore, now I'm getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function glob()" but I think I'll create a new question about that.

Comment: You should do yourself a favor and consider a system admistrator to review your setup so you have some safety everything went smooth. `glob()` not existing sounds like you've been calling for problems.

Comment: Thanks, I've reinstalled PHP and now the installation is ok, no weird glob() errors. It seems that I cannot instantiate any models now, everytime I try to do it I get an error saying that the class is not found.

Comment: I have no kohana specifc experience, but maybe this helps: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/libraries

Comment: Dude you are a genious! The problem was here: "Library class names and file names begin with a capitalized letter". Changed calafate_orm to Calafate_orm and that did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should extend Model instead of Facebook in Facebook_Model.

Answer (score 0):

As hakre said in the comments and as it's stated [here](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/libraries) "Library class names and file names begin with a capitalized letter"

I changed the file and class to start with C and that fixed the problem.

When I moved the project to Ubuntu I changed every file name to lower case, in the case of Libraries that was wrong.

Thanks to all and I hope this helps anyone in the future.